# C# Xamarin - Device.StartTimer works only 1 day

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have problem with this code:

```
            Device.StartTimer(seconds, () => {

                if (user.ToString("HH:mm") == DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"))
                {

                        LoadCallLog();
                    Thread.Sleep(60000);
                }

                return true;
            });
```

User is time from database. I want every day when is user = current time call method `LoadCallLog()`, but it call method only first day. When is next day method won't call. Do someone have idea what's wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: is the problem that the timer is not firing on the second day, or that the comparison fails?

Comment: That's question. I dont have idea what's wrong.

Comment: you need to do some basic debugging to figure this out

Comment: I can't wait day to check it

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `Thread.Sleep`, especially on Xamarin.

Comment: That's not the problem i think

Comment: `I can't wait day to check it`, you can reduce the time and test, it's the same. Are you apps waiting a day in background? The app won't work at background in iOS and it may killed by system in Android.